# How to set the xtick position for secondary axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, figure

I want to create a secondary xaxis at the top which has an inverse relation with the major xaxis at the bottom. I followed the official tutorial [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) and have the following codes:

```
def forward(x):
    return 10/x

def backward(y):
    return 10/y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0.14, 1.4])
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward, backward))
secax.set_xticks(np.array([10,20,40,70]))  # does not work!
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the xticks at the top are not at the right place. They are bunched together in the left due to the inverse function applied. How do I manually set the position of the xticks? (e.g. at 10,20,40,70)

Edit:
Just to make it more clear, the ticks are at the right place, but there are too many tickss as shown in the figure. In this case, I only want the ticks at 10, 20, 40, 70 (I don't want the ticks at 30, 50 and 60 as we can't see all the tick numbers clearly)
[image]

Comment: Why do you they aren't at right place ? I see that 70 is on top of 0.14 .. which looks correct to me. What do you expect to see?

Comment: The location is at the right place, but I want to control how many ticks there are. Right now the above code gives too many ticks on the left.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Try updating your matplotlib.

Comment: @lostin my matplotlib is version 3.1.3. I can't upgrade it to the latest 3.2.1 for some reason, and so now I'm looking for alternative ways to control which ticks appear.

Answer (score 2):

I believe either you missed import statement for numpy or you need to update you matplotlib. Below works fine for me -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def forward(x):
    return 10/x

def backward(y):
    return 10/y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0.14, 1.4])
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward, backward))
secax.set_xticks(np.array([10,20,40,70]))  # does not work!
plt.show()
```

Check your version -

```
import matplotlib
print (matplotlib.__version__)
```

If above doesn't print 3.2.1. try below -

```
 pip install matplotlib==3.2.1
```

[image]

Comment: Considering the OP update, the problem indeed does not lie in the code, which I agree is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve.

If you want a linear relationship at the top, this might be relevant:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0.14, 1.4])
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(lambda x: 77 - 50 * x,
                                             lambda y: (77 - y) / 50))
secax.set_xticks(np.array([10, 20, 40, 70]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The top axis does not give a linear relationship, and they are at the right place. What I want is to control how many ticks there are.

Comment: What do you mean by "The top axis does not give a linear relationship"? It is pretty obvious that there is twice as much space between 20 and 40 compared to 10 and 20, as well as three times as much space between 40 and 70 using the same comparison. Additionally, both functions are linear in their argument.